# Sending from all processor to root, using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv.

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing, sendmessage, 2d-vector

I have trouble to collect some data from all processors to the root, here is one example of what I want to do:

I have a couple of pairs (actually they are edges) in each processor and ideally want to send them to the root, or if there is no way I can send their corresponding index (one number instead of pairs.

For example:

```
Processor 0: sends {(0,5), (1,6)} to root, or it sould send {5,17}
Processor 1: sends {(2,3)} to root, or it sould send {14}
Processor 2: sends {} to root, or it sould send {}
Processor 3: sends {(4,0)} to root, or it sould send {20}
```

I am wondering what is the best way to store the pairs or numbers and send and receive them. I ideally I prefer to store them in a 2d vector since from the beginning I don`t know how much space I need, and receive them again in a 2D vector. I know it might not possible or might be very complicated.

This is a pseudocode of the procedure I am looking for but don`t know how to implement in MPI.

```
vector<vector<int > >allSelectedEdges;
vector<vector<int > >selectedEdgesLocal; 
int edgeCount=0;   
if(my_rank!=0){                          
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < nVertex; ++j)
                if (some conditions)
                {
                    vector<int> tempEdge;
                    tempEdge.push_back(displs[my_rank]+i);
                    tempEdge.push_back(j);
                    selectedEdgesLocal.push_back(tempEdge);
                    edgeCount++;
                }
        }
        "send selectedEdgesLocal to root"
}else
{
      "root recieve sselectedEdgesLocal and store in allSelectedEdges"
}
```

I thought about MPI_Gatherv as well but seems that doesn`t help. Got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5040879/3914860)

```
vector<vector<int > >selectedEdgesLocal; 
int edgeCount=0;                            
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < nVertex; ++j)
        if (some conditions)
        {
            vector<int> tempEdge;
            tempEdge.push_back(displs[my_rank]+i);
            tempEdge.push_back(j);
            selectedEdgesLocal.push_back(tempEdge);
            edgeCount++;
         }
int NumdgesToAdd;
MPI_Reduce(&edgeCount, &NumdgesToAdd, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

vector<vector<int > > allSelectedEdges(NumdgesToAdd);

int rcounts[comm_size];
int rdisp[comm_size];
int sumE=0;
for(int i=0; i<comm_size; ++i) {
    rcounts[i] = edgeCount;
    rdisp[i]=sumE;
    sumE+=edgeCount;
}

MPI_Gatherv(&selectedEdgesLocal.front(), rcounts[my_rank], MPI_INT, &allSelectedEdges.front(), rcounts, rdisp, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: you first need to gather all the `edgeCount` on the root rank, and then you can allocate `allSelectedEdges` and build `rcounts` and `rdisp`

Comment: Do you know the maximum count of values you'd want to send from each process to the root?  For example is it "up to 2" or "up to 10" or is it an unlimited number?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Each processor holds some rows of a matrix(graph), the count can be up to the number of items in each processor.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet you mean something similar to the second solution I explained?why the root rank should know all edgeCount?

Comment: `rcounts` and `rdisp` are only relevant on the root rank, so since each rank has its own `edgeCount`, the root rank should know all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update my code as follows, and it is working now.

```
vector <int> selectedEdgesIndicesLocal;

    int edgeCount=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < nVertex; ++j)
            if (some condistions)
            {
                int index=...;
                selectedEdgesIndicesLocal.push_back(index);
                edgeCount++;
            }

    int NumEdgesToAdd;
    MPI_Reduce(&edgeCount, &NumEdgesToAdd, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int *edgeCountsInRoot;
    if (my_rank == 0)edgeCountsInRoot = (int *)malloc(comm_size * sizeof(int));
    MPI_Gather(&edgeCount, 1, MPI_INT, edgeCountsInRoot, 1, MPI_INT, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int *allSelectedIndicesEdges;
    if (my_rank == 0)allSelectedIndicesEdges = (int *)malloc(NumEdgesToAdd * sizeof(int));

    int * edgeCounts, *edgeDisp;

    cout<<edgeCount<<endl;
    if (my_rank==0) {
        edgeCounts= (int *)malloc(comm_size * sizeof(int));
        edgeDisp= (int *)malloc(comm_size * sizeof(int));
        int edgeSum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<comm_size; ++i) {
            edgeCounts[i] = edgeCountsInRoot[i];
            edgeDisp[i]=edgeSum;
            edgeSum+=edgeCountsInRoot[i];
        }
    }
    MPI_Gatherv(&selectedEdgesIndicesLocal.front(), edgeCount, MPI_INT, &allSelectedIndicesEdges[0], edgeCounts,edgeDisp, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Gather for this.  The problem is that each process has a different number of values to send to the root.  So you can either determine the maximum number of values to send, and have each process send that many values (with unused values being NAN for example), or do what Gilles Gouaillardet suggested in a comment, and use two steps:

1. Have each process compute the number of values it needs to send.  Gather these counts to the root as `rcounts`.
2. Use Gather to collect the values--now that root process knows `rcounts`, it can easily compute `rdisp` as the cumulative sum of `rcounts`.

The "use a fixed maximum number of values and fill unused slots with NAN" is simpler and will work well if the total amount of data is small.  If the total amount of data is large and the number of values sent by each process is quite different, the two-step solution is probably more efficient.

Comment: note you can directly `MPI_Gather(..., recvbuf=rcounts, ...)` so the root rank only has to compute `rdisp`